# (i) Create a table from existing one and (ii) display detailed data for which total is stored in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

1. From a table **t1**
   **product_id** | **quantity** | **total_amount**

   I want to create a table **t2** with the columns
   **id** | **product_id** | total_amount/quantity AS **product_price**
2. I want each record (**t2.product_id**, **t2.product_price**) to be shown **t1.quantity** times for the respective product:

   1 | 400
    1 | 400
    1 | 400
    2 |  75
    2 |  75

Could you please tell me, how can I do this using bare SQL?

Comment: Please post the SQL query that is failing.

Comment: I think you cannot do this as a simple SQL query. You should write the logic of what you want in some other programming language, or with a stored procedure.

Comment: Could you, please, re-phrase "I want each t2.product_id,t2.product_price to replicated by t1.quantity for the same product"? Some sample data would really be helpful.

Comment: t1.(product_id, quantity,total_amount) contains:(1,3,1200),(2,2,150)

Comment: t1.(product_id, quantity,total_amount) contains:(1,3,1200),(2,2,150)... how can i show list of data from t1 that contains tow columns (product_id,price) with following data (1,400),(1,400),(1,400),(2,75),(2,75) using select statement ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to create the table, you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE T2 AS
  SELECT
    @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS id
    , product_id
    , total_amount / quantity AS product_price
  FROM t1, (SELECT @rowid := 0) AS firstID
  ORDER BY product_id
;
```

For the second part of your request, you could try:

```
SELECT
  T.product_id
  , T.total_amount / T.quantity AS price
FROM T1 T CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT A.n + B.n * 10 + 1 n
   FROM
     (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
        UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
        UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) A
     , (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
          UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
          UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) B
   ORDER BY n
  ) N
WHERE N.n <= T.quantity
ORDER BY product_id
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0c8c/2).

Please comment if this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: @JalalJadhijazi Did you have a chance to check, whether this meets your requirements?